# SQL query to calculate stock order data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with orders for shares of stocks that looks like this:

[image]

The first column is the ID of the respective stock, the second column is the order price, third column is whether its a bid (buy) or an ask (sell) and finally the the last column is the volume remaining in this order.

What I'm trying to do is get these values:

- Highest and lowest bid prices and highest and lowest ask prices.
- sum of the volume at highest bid and sum of volume at lowest ask

I realize this is pretty complicated query and it's likely going to involve one (or probably several sub-queries) but what I have so far is this:

```
SELECT
  SYMBOL_CODE as symbol_code,
  MAX(ORDER_PRICE) as highest_bid,
  MIN(ORDER_PRICE) as lowest_bid,
  SUM(VOLUME_TRADED)
FROM ORDERS
WHERE
  ORDER_TYPE = 'buy'
GROUP BY
  SYMBOL_CODE
order by
  SYMBOL_CODE;
```

There are two issues with this as I see it, first of all, it sums the volume of all the prices, not the prices of highest bid orders only, couldnt figure out how to do that and secondly, this only does the bids, I'd have to write another query for the asks. I tried grouping by order_type but I didn't get the expected result (stocks had 1 or 2 rows in result depending on whether they had a bid/ask order or both)

Comment: Edit the question add expected result.

Comment: I'd have to add a lot of example data so that you can see how they affect the output. I can explain the required values more if they're not clear enough. I can also add the `.sql` file

Comment: Sample of your expected output will help

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the table for the highest and lowest price using `row_number()`, and then do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    symbol_code,
    max(case when order_type = 'buy' and rn_high = 1 then order_price end) highest_bid,
    sum(case when order_type = 'buy' and rn_high = 1 then volume_traded end) volume_at_highest_bid,
    min(case when order_type = 'sell' and rn_low = 1 then order_price end) lowest_ask,
    sum(case when order_type = 'sell' and rn_low = 1 then volume_traded end) volume_at_lowest_ask
from (
    select
        o.*,
        row_number() over(partition by symbol_code, order_type order by order_price) rn_low,
        row_number() over(partition by symbol_code, order_type order by order_price desc) rn_high
    from orders o
) t
where 
    order_type = 'buy' and rn_high = 1
    or (order_type = 'sell' and rn_low = 1)
group by symbol_code
```

Comment: what is rn_high and rn_low?

Comment: @ninesalt: these are `row_number()`s, that we use to identify the highest bid and lowest ask.

Comment: @ninesalt they are essentially ranks.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying `Invalid column name 'volume_traded'.` even though that's what the column is named

Comment: Ok now it executes but there a lot of nulls. Also this doesn't select lowest bid and highest ask

Answer (score 0):

I created a view as Follows to keep all the specified details and then just select from the view depending on

> order_volume

and

> type

columns.

```
alter view MinMax as
select [SYMBOL_CODE] as Symbol,
        MAX(ORDER_PRICE) as 'Price',
        'Max' as 'Type',
        case max(order_type) when 'buy' then 'BID'  
        else 'ASK'
        end as 'Order Type' ,
        'Order' as 'Order_Volume'
        FROM ORDERS
where ORDER_PRICE in(select MAX(ORDER_PRICE) FROM ORDERS)
group by [SYMBOL_CODE]
union 
select SYMBOL_CODE ,
        sum(VOLUME_TRADED),
        'Max',
        case max(order_type) when 'buy' then 'BID'
        else 'ASK'
        end ,
        'Order'
        FROM ORDERS
where VOLUME_TRADED in(select MAX(VOLUME_TRADED) FROM ORDERS)
group by [SYMBOL_CODE]
union
select SYMBOL_CODE as Symbol,
       MAX(ORDER_PRICE),
       'Max',
       'BID',
        'Volume' 
        FROM ORDERS
where VOLUME_TRADED in(select MAX(VOLUME_TRADED) FROM ORDERS) and order_type='buy'
group by [SYMBOL_CODE]
union
select SYMBOL_CODE,
       MAX(ORDER_PRICE),
        'Min',
        'ASK',
        'Volume'
        FROM ORDERS
where VOLUME_TRADED in(select min(VOLUME_TRADED) FROM ORDERS) and order_type='sell'
group by [SYMBOL_CODE]
```

I also added a new column named 'OrderType' if you want to get in the orders depending also on budget type. 
Select from the View to get the specified result.

```
Select * from minmax
```

If you want only SYMBOL_ID and price then:

```
select symbol,price from minmax
```

Comment: MAX(SYMBOL_CODE)?

Comment: @ninesalt i thought you wanted only the min and max rows sorry. I made some changes using GroupBy. I hope it helps you right now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using The Min()/Max() function in addition to the Partition-- function?
That way you can "split" the query results into each "symbol code"-partition and get the respective Min/Max

Because it seems like, what you really want to do is look at all data for a certain "symbol code", and then "iterate" through them

Answer (score 0):

I think window functions and appropriate aggregation do what you want:

```
select symbol_code, max_buy, min_ask,
       sum(case when order_type = 'buy' and order_price = max_buy then volume_traded) as max_buy_volume,
       sum(case when order_type = 'sell' and order_price = min_ask then volume_traded) as min_ask_volume
from (select o.*,
             max(case when order_type = 'buy' then order_price end) over (partition by symbol_code) as max_buy,
             min(case when order_type = 'sell' then order_price end) over (partition by symbol_code) as min_ask
       from orders o
      ) o
group by symbol_code, max_buy, min_ask;
```

Comment: @ninesalt . . . There is no obvious syntax error around an of the `o`s.